# How to add operation in tensorflow with Xcode

Tags: xcode, c++11, tensorflow

Recently, I am trying to learn how to add a new operation in tensorflow with Xcode for mac os. However, I do not find the tensorflow header file and I have installed tensorlfow with pip. I am not sure how to solve this problem. The following code is public in tensorlfow documentation.

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });
```

I just want to repeat it, but I can not find the path of tensorflow. Thank you so much, everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either work in the TensorFlow repository using bazel or you need to write you own makefile and just use the pip package.

If you are just creating an operation for TensorFlow and you are using v1.9 you can lookup these information from the pip package using

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())
print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib()
```

However you might need [much more information](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow-cmake/blob/42e90b31d2b14fb453d4bc5f377f5d828e27afab/cmake/modules/FindTensorFlow.cmake#L45) to compile you code.